# Add class to div when woocommerce cart is empty

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I would like to add a class to (or directly style) an element that contains the cart count ONLY when the cart is empty.

Below is the code that I am currently using which is working great. The cart count is working great but the color does not update.

header.php  (cart count added after the cart icon in menu)

```
?>          
<div class="counter_bubble">
        <a href="/cart">
            <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
            $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
            echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
            ?></span>
        </a>
</div>
<?php
```

functions.php  (enqueue custom javascript + cart refresh)

```
// ADD CUSTOM JS FILE FROM CHILD THEME
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bubblescript');

function bubblescript() {
    wp_enqueue_script( '_tandt-main', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/../Graffont/js/gft-script.js', array("jquery"), $my_js_ver, true );
}

// REFRESH CART FRAGMENTS (ITEM COUNT) SO CORRECT NUMBER IS ALWAYS SHOWN
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'refresh_cart_count', 50, 1 );

function refresh_cart_count( $fragments ){
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <span class="counter" id="cart-count"><?php
    $cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    echo sprintf ( _n( '%d', '%d', $cart_count ), $cart_count );
    ?></span>
    <?php
     $fragments['#cart-count'] = ob_get_clean();

    return $fragments;
}
```

gft-script.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

function changecartbubble() {
    if ($('body').find('#cart-count').length > 0) {
        if (parseInt($('#cart-count').html()) > 0) {
            // cart has number > 0 so cart has items
            //change background class
            $('#cart-count').addClass('other-background-of-bubble');
        }
        else {
            // cart has no number so cart has no items
            //remove background class
            $('#cart-count').removeClass('other-background-of-bubble');
        }
    }
}

});
```

style.css - Current CSS

```
.counter {
    background-color: #ff0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
}

.other-background-of-bubble{
    background-color:red!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function on document ready and whenever cart is updated by ajax.

Javascript/jQuery:

```
function changecartbubble() {
    if ($('body').find('#cart-count').length > 0) {
        if (parseInt($('#cart-count').html()) > 0) {
            // cart has number > 0 so cart has items
            //change background class
            $('#cart-count').addClass('other-background-of-bubble');
        }
        else {
            // cart has no number so cart has no items
            //remove background class
            $('#cart-count').removeClass('other-background-of-bubble');
        }
    }
}
```

Style:

```
.other-background-of-bubble{
    background:red!important;
}
```

Comment: Based on your suggestions I added a wp_enque_script to my functions.php that calls on a js file with your code. The code in the js file is surrouned by jQuery(document).ready(function($) { //CODE// });  but i did not see any change. Any further suggestions on how to implement?

Comment: Make sure you don't see any errors in console, and jQuery is loaded successfully before calling the function. Also, make sure you have correct order of scripts in functions.php

Comment: I have tested the above javascript function, and it is working fine.
What is the output you are seeing inside #cart-count after echoing everything?

Comment: Thanks for following up and for your help. I am a bit of a noob so I might be missing something. I have updated my original question with the new code I added. There are no errors in the console and i do not see the class being echoed. Output with item in cart is <span id="cart-count" class="counter">1</span>   - If it helps to see in action, site is https://graffont.com

Comment: I see error in console when I run the function changecartbubble();

Comment: "missing { before function body" is that what you're seeing? Any idea on how to fix?